# How to create my own function in the Entity in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

I would like to override the Entities, Form ect.. in Symfony 2 to create my own functions. This to don't loose my code when i re-generate my Model from my database.

It was easy in symfony 1.4 because symfony generate the model and all the override files but i don't understand how to in Symfony 2

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried extending the Entity (inheritance) and creating whatever methods you need there?

Comment: [Just follow their docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html).

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 2 uses mapper files or anotations to generates entites base setters/getters. And it creates entities backup files. So it's safe to create own logic in enties, but it's better keep entities as light as possible and move logic to services/manages.